# Issue with setting an image as a nested state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have a react frontend which is responsible for getting inputs to create a new user for my app. It hits the backend server when the user submits the form. In that form, I have a file input to allow  a user to select an avatar. On the backend, I use rails active storage to handle saving that image to aws. The issue here is I want to save the image as a nested prop under the user state. So given the constructor method of the UserForm Component;

[image]

I have a few text inputs for the full name, email and password and a file input for the avatar. The idea is to grab all of that and send it as a formdata to the rails backend. I can then grab the entire user params and create a new user on the backend.

So here's my inputs:
[image]

Here's my code when a user types into the text fields. It saves the inputs to the nested state of the User state:

[image]

The issue is when Im trying to attach the image and save it under User.avatar state.

[image]

When I do Console.log(file), I get this which is correct, it show the image:

[image]

But when I check state User.Avatar, it shows this. user.avatar is an empty object!
[image]

But if I just set the image directly on a top level state like this:
[image]

The state for file is showing up fine:
[image]

Any ideas why this is happening? Its so weird!

**Edit 1**

According to a solution below by Ilia, just send it to the backend. So assuming I send it to the backend with avatar saved under the user object in state. Here's my code which does that:

```
   submitUser = async () => {    
    let formData = new FormData();

    formData.set("user", JSON.stringify(this.state.user));    

    const res = await axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: '/users/',
      data: formData,
      headers: {
      'content-type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${formData._boundary}`,
      },
    });
```

On my rails backend:

```
def create    
    @user = User.new(user_params)    

    if @user.save
      flash[:notice] = "Welcome #{@user.full_name}"
      render json: { status: true }
      session[:user_id] = @user.id     
    else
      flash[:error] = "Please fix the following error(s)"
      render json: { error: @user.errors.messages }
    end
  end
```

And my strogn params is handling the params (debugging code in here):

```
def user_params       
    json_params = ActionController::Parameters.new( JSON.parse(params[:user]) )
    binding.pry     
    res = json_params.require(:user).permit(:email, :full_name, :password)

    res
  end
```

My avatar is jsut an empty obj..

[image]

I'm not sure what you meant by making it as an image source?

Comment: add code as text instead of screenshots

Comment: I am confused, let's say that you want to save file as this.state.avater?

Comment: @Kuo-hsuanHsu I could save the file to this.state.avatar, but I want to avoid doing that if possible. I'd just like to save it all under user params so that I could use my existing rails backend to create a user without additional configuration

Answer (score 1):

I have came across with the same issue before, the state actually is holding the file value but for unknown reason (for me) it does not shows, send that to backend and you will see that file is received correctly, you can as well set it as an image source to ensure that file is actually received!

Comment: Hey, thanks for some input. I've written up an edit 1 where I tried sending the data to the backend but its still an empty object...